# Do I have to change a namespace when moving files in c# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I'm moving files in my project and I cannot find clear answer - is namespace  connected with location of the file? Do I need to change namespace when moving files?

Comment: You can try and see, this is the easiest way.

Comment: Namespace is not connected with file location, therefore you do not need to change it when moving files.

Comment: Although it isn't connected in anyway, some would suggest that you do change the namespace to match but that is personal preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is namespace connected with location of the file?

Only by convention. It is not required, nor enforced by the compiler or runtime.

Note that in C#, you can nest namespaces, and can declare more than one namespace at any given level of nesting. Obviously only one declared namespace in a file can actually match the file's location. So it would not even be possible to require namespaces to match the file name, without abandoning those features in C#.

> Do I need to change namespace when moving files?

No. See above.

You may be interested in related Stack Overflow Q&A's on the topic:

- [How to make the C# namespace work like Java Packages so they rename automatically when moving them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10646590)
- [How do I fix Visual Studio (2013) namespace collision when moving files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32619981)
- [Should the folders in a solution match the namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4664)

The first two relate to management of files and namespaces when changing the location of source files, while the third is more about generally accepted conventions.